# valgrind not report mem leak in a function when use in test program

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

i am getting below memory leak reported by valgrind.

```
==51== 200 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 348 of 417
==51==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==51==    by 0x508CF54: __libc_alloc_buffer_allocate (alloc_buffer_allocate.c:26)
==51==    by 0x5130628: alloc_buffer_allocate (alloc_buffer.h:143)
==51==    by 0x5130628: __resolv_conf_allocate (resolv_conf.c:411)
==51==    by 0x512DE21: __resolv_conf_load (res_init.c:592)
==51==    by 0x5130232: __resolv_conf_get_current (resolv_conf.c:163)
==51==    by 0x512E3D4: __res_vinit (res_init.c:614)
==51==    by 0x512F5CF: maybe_init (resolv_context.c:122)
==51==    by 0x512F5CF: context_get (resolv_context.c:184)
==51==    by 0x512F5CF: context_get (resolv_context.c:176)
==51==    by 0x512F5CF: __resolv_context_get (resolv_context.c:195)
==51==    by 0x511E63F: gethostbyname (getXXbyYY.c:105)
==51==    by 0x153745: getinterfaceip (sctpThread.cpp:72)
==51==    by 0x153745: startPrometheus(sctp_params&) (sctpThread.cpp:539)
==51==    by 0x145051: main (sctpThread.cpp:608)
==51==
```

following it the source code from where this is reported

```
char* getinterfaceip()
{
   char hostname[256];
   char *IP;
   struct hostent *host_entry;
   int retVal;
   retVal = gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname));
   if ( retVal == -1 )
       return NULL;
   host_entry = gethostbyname(hostname);
   if ( host_entry == NULL )
       return NULL;
   IP = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*) host_entry->h_addr_list[0]));
   return IP;
}

void startPrometheus(sctp_params_t &sctpParams) {
    auto podName = std::getenv("POD_NAME");
    string metric = "E2TBeta";
    if (strstr(podName, "alpha") != NULL) {
        metric = "E2TAlpha";
    }
    //Get eth0 interface IP
    char* host = getinterfaceip();
    string hostip = host;

    sctpParams.prometheusFamily = &BuildCounter()
            .Name(metric.c_str())
            .Help("E2T instance metrics")
            .Labels({{"POD_NAME", sctpParams.podName}})
            .Register(*sctpParams.prometheusRegistry);

    string prometheusPath;
    if (hostip.empty())
        prometheusPath = sctpParams.prometheusPort + "," + "[::]:" + sctpParams.prometheusPort;
}
```

but if i use the same getinterfaceip() function in my simple c program as below and try with valgrind it does not report any leak. does it mean that mem leak is not in getinterfaceip() function as reported?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

main()
{
   char hostname[256];
   char *IP;
   struct hostent *host_entry;
   int retVal;
   retVal = gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname));
   if ( retVal == -1 )
       return NULL;
   host_entry = gethostbyname(hostname);
   if ( host_entry == NULL )
       return NULL;
   IP = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*) host_entry->h_addr_list[0]));
   printf("%s", IP);
   sleep(300);
}
```

Comment: While it won't help you with the question or the apparent difference between calling `gethostbyname` in `main` or in another function, the reported leak is a false positive. The `gethostbyname` have a single buffer shared between all calls to it, and it's likely this allocation is part of that. It's one of the reasons it has been obsoleted by `getaddrinfo`. Also `inet_ntoa` have been obsoleted by `inet_ntop`. The memory will be released by the OS on process exit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which OS, CPU or compiler you are using. So I'm going to guess Linux amd64 GCC.

This may be a GNU libc bug.

GNU libc has a function, __libc_freeres(), that Valgrind calls on a *clean* exit to free memory like this. A leak like this means one of the following

1. Your Valgrind version is too old
2. You are using a system without __libc_freeres
3. Valgrind is failing to locate and call __libc_freeres
4. GNU libc changed to add an allocation that is missing from _libc_freeres, in other words a bug in GNU libc

You can test whether it is one of the first three points by running Valgrind with `-v -v` (the verbose flags stack).

You should see

```
--2474793-- Caught __NR_exit; running __gnu_cxx::__freeres and __libc_freeres() wrapper
```

(the PID will very likely be different)

Comment: I am using a 3rd party code which is using gethostname() where valgrind report mem leak. why valgrind should call  __libc_freeres() to free memory which is allocated by gethostname() ?  it is 3rd party code's responsibility to clean its memory?? is't it?   and valgrind will allocate and free mem? valgrind's job is to show mem leak and not to consume by itself. please explain

Comment: As @Some programmer dude said, GNU libc uses 'lazy deallocation' (does not bother to dealocate) for some one-off buffers. These leaks are mostly harmless and can be ignored. There is no way for users to free the memory (and it may not be safe to do so). Valgrind triggers the deallocation so that users see no leaks.

Comment: could not get this point  "There is no way for users to free the memory"   but as i know user has free() function to free the memry in C library. "Valgrind triggers the deallocation" but why valgrind's does it ? when i do not use valgrind then it will be done by "lazy dellocation" ? if yes then why valgrind is showing this as a mem leak in my 3 rd party project and do not show when i run in a simple program? as a newbie in valgrind how can now know that some thing is false positicve as in this case? any symptome of false positive?

Comment: Please read my previous comment more carefully. How are you going to call free if you don't have the pointer to allocated memory? For symptoms of false positives, that's fairly difficult and requires experience. libc names like buffer_allocate" give a clue.